# how to change the title of Surefire HTML report?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I was able to change the name of the Surefire report but is it possible to change the title on the HTML report as well?

Like in place of "Surefire Report" I want custom text. I have below in the Surefire plugin and it updates the HTML report name and how to update the title once we open the report and it comes on top of the report as "Surefire Report"?

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputName>Results-${env} Environment</outputName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the documentation: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-only-mojo.html#title ?

Comment: It is no longer possible to change the title. The current version 3.2.1 of the "Maven Surefire Report Plugin" does not provide a `title` option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just passed the `-Dsurefire.report.title="test"` via command line and it changed the title.

Comment: It is no longer possible to change the title. The current version 3.2.1 of the "Maven Surefire Report Plugin" does not provide a `title` option.